# Подвисает html-страница после отправки формы

Tags: html, ajax

Форма в модальном окне. После отправки формы форма закрывается и страница не реагирует, пока еще раз не произойдет событие щелчка мыши на кнопке вызова модального окна.   Вот страница на сервере: http://craft.transkribator.ru/

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Кнопка</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">                
            <h4 class="modal-title">Заполните форму</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ваша электронная почта</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Введите email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Имя</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Записаться</button>
          </div>              
      </form>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->



$(function() {  
$("form").submit(function() { 
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", 
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
            $("form").css('display','none');
            $(".modal-title").html("Ваши данные успешно отправлены");       
            $("#myModal").fadeOut(700);
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допишите в `$('#myModal').modal('toggle')` после `$("#myModal").fadeOut(700)`, [смотрите](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) в документацию и используйте то, что вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо - все работает. Не нужно было путать мух с котлетами. `$("form").submit(function(e) { 
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "mail.php", 
   data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
   $("form").css('display','none');
   $(".modal-title").html("Ваши данные успешно отправлены").fadeOut(1000);
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
   }, 1000);    
  });`

Answer (score 1):

```
return false;
```

Не проверял, но возможно ошибка в этом? Ты при обработке

```
$("form").submit(function() { ..........
```

Так понимаю этим действием пытаешься блокировать стандартное действие отправщика формы. Возможно, если ты поставишь перед

```
var th = $(this);
```

код

```
e.preventDefault();
```

а в функции .submit(function() передашь .submit(function(e)
у тебя перестанет виснуть, ну и уберёшь если return false;

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: если убрать `return false`, то срабатывает стандартное действие отправщика формы и JQuery не работает

Comment: e.preventDefault; должен убирать стандартное действие отправщика формы. каким браузером пользуешься? попробуй вывести в консоль переменную e. Она вообще у тебя выводится? Некоторые браузеры вместо неё поддерживают переменную event

Comment: `common.js:4 m.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "submit", timeStamp: 10947.965000000002, jQuery111102934004934217971: true, isDefaultPrevented: function…}`

Comment: переменная выводится, браузер Chrome

Comment: попробуй обрабатывать не form.submit, а к примеру некий button.click, может поможет, всё тоже самое, только событие другое, точно также будешь форму сериализовать $('form').serialize()

Comment: `$("#buts").click(function(e){
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "mail.php", 
   data: $("form").serialize()
  }).done(function() {
   $("form").css('display','none');
   $(".modal-title").html("Ваши данные успешно отправлены");  
   $("#myModal").fadeOut(3000);`
  }); та же песня. После отправки формы, форма растворяется после 3сек и окно неактивно, пока не нажмешь кнопку отправки. Стандартная отправка - без ajax - отрабатывает нормально и после отправки формы окно активно

Comment: Возможно, есть какая-то функция jquery, которую можно было бы засунуть в конец кода для активации страницы? Почему при мертвой странице, только клик в области кнопки отправки возвращает страницу к жизни?

Comment: Еще момент: может, не точно выразился - страница не виснет, а исчезает боковая прокрутка и нет возможности для прокрутки, пока не кликнешь снова на кнопку отправки